# Why didn't Holly get angry with Dwight about this prank?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-office

In *The Office* episode where Dwight "pranked" Holly into thinking that Kevin is "special", why didn't she get angry at Dwight and confront him for what he has done to her?

Comment: Because it wouldn't make for good comedy, presumably. There are many situations where people get away with seemingly extremely unrespectful things - recently, for example, we had [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/why-was-erin-and-andy-not-fired-after-they-flipped-out-on-nellie-robert).

Comment: @Joachim with the question you linked, I didn't feel what I have felt with the episode I mentioned - the lack of closure on a story bit. And in my opinion, Dwight awkwardly trying to act, like he didn't start the joke would make for a good comedy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't have any references or anything, but this has always seemed reasonable to me, for the following reasons:

I think the easiest explanation is that she was much more *embarrassed* than she was angry.  She accepted what Dwight said at face value and apparently never tried to look into it any further to make sure that was the case.    As a HR rep, she should really **know** if one of the workers is mentally challenged.  The fact that she not only didn't know that, but believed Dwight without question, is probably seen as a huge personal mistake on her part.

Based on what we see in the show, Holly doesn't seem like the type of person who would jump at blaming others if she is also responsible.  In this case, she presumably had the resources to figure out that Kevin was not on a special work program.  She really should have known that, especially since it was not her first day when she got upset with Angela for calling Kevin an idiot.

We can probably put a lot of the blame on Dunder Mifflin as well, for only giving Toby 1 day to train Holly; but at the end of the day, it seems in character for Holly to blame herself instead of Dwight.

Comment: Well but DM probably figured 1 day was enough since Holly already knew DM HR Procedures and policy having come down from Nashua. So Toby just needed to fill-in Holly on the "basic info" of the Scranton branch (where things were, who did what, current conditions in the office, Michael will hate you....period, etc.) before he headed out for the jury leave, knowing he'd be back later.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Yet it wasn't sufficient enough for Holly not to realize that Dwight was just messing with her.  I think Toby actually had decent reasons to be skeptical about only one day of training.  A day really isn't that much time to get settled, a feel for the office, and a feel for the workers.

Comment: remember too that DM was already being poorly run by the execs and senior management. It was being run into the ground as we later see just before the Sabre merger. So poor planning decisions were made on their part as to how long Toby would have to train Holly before jury leave.

Comment: I am accepting the answer, since it made me realize after watching the scene again, that Holly's face actually shows, that she realizes it is her mistake and Dwight is not to blame here. But I still lack the closure after the scene and think that Dwight awkward reaction after being confronted by Holly could be a great scene.